# Doctrine 2: There is no column with name '$columnName' on table '$table'

Tags: doctrine-orm

When I do:

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update
```

Doctrine 2.4 gives me this error:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
There is no column with name 'resource_id' on table 'role_resource'.
```

My actual MySQL database schema has the column and the table, as evident from running this command (no errors thrown):

```
mysql> select resource_id from role_resource;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Thus, the error must be somewhere in the Doctrine's representation of the schema.  I did a `var_dump()` of `$this` object, and here is what I get (partial):

```
object(Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table)#546 (10) {
    ["_name"   :protected] => string(13) "role_resource"
    ["_columns":protected] => array(0) { }
```

Note that indeed, the `_columns` key does not contain any columns, which is [how Doctrine checks for column names](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L590).

In my case, the partial trace dump is as follows:

- [SchemaException.php#L85](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/SchemaException.php#L85)
- [Table.php#L252](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L252)
- [Table.php#L161](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L161)

Reading other posts with similar problem, seem to suggest that I may have an error in the column case (upper vs lower).  While it is possible I have missed something, but looking over my actual schema on the Database and the Annotations in my code seem to suggest a match (all lowercase).  Similarly, [Doctrine2's code does incorporate checks for such casing errors](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema/Table.php#L588).  So I am ruling out the error casing possibility.

Another post I've seen suggests that there may be an error in my Annotations, i.e. wrong naming, syntax, or `id` placement.  I don't know, I checked it and it seems fine.  Here is what I have:

```
class Role implements HierarchicalRoleInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ModuleName\Entity\Resource")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_resource",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="resource_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $resource;
```

So at the moment, I am stuck, and unable to use the ORM's schema-generation tools.  This is a persistent error.  I have scraped my database, generated schema anew using ORM, but still get stuck on this error whenever I try to do an update via ORM, as I describe in this post.  Where perhaps should I look next?

---

Update:  traced it to [this code](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php#L630):
$sql before this line ==

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Field, 
    COLUMN_TYPE AS Type,
    IS_NULLABLE AS `Null`,
    COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`,
    COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`,
    EXTRA AS Extra,
    COLUMN_COMMENT AS Comment,
    CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS CharacterSet,
    COLLATION_NAME AS CollactionName,
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'loginauth' AND TABLE_NAME = 'role_resource'
```

which when I run it form MySQL prompt, returns (some columns were trimmed):

```
+-------------+---------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type    | Null | Key | CharacterSet | CollactionName |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
| role_id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL         | NULL           |    
| resource_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL         | NULL           |
+-------------+---------+------+-----+--------------+----------------+
```

and the `$this->executeQuery($sql, $params, $types)` returns the proper(?) statement that runs fine on my prompt, but when `->fetchAll()` is called, specifically this [fetchAll()](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/ResultStatement.php#L76) it breaks down and returns an empty array.  Can I have someone make sense out of this?

MORE:

Essentially, from above links, `$this->executeQuery($sql, $params, $types)` returns:

```
object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement)#531 (1) {
    ["queryString"]=> string(332) "SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Field, COLUMN_TYPE AS Type, IS_NULLABLE AS `Null`, COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS Extra, COLUMN_COMMENT AS Comment, CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS CharacterSet, COLLATION_NAME AS CollactionName FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'loginauth' AND TABLE_NAME = 'role_resource'"
}
```

but then `$this->executeQuery($sql, $params, $types)->fetchAll()` (adding fetchAll()), returns this:

```
array(0) {
}
```

And that is so sad my friends :(  because I don't know why it returns an empty array, when the statement in queryString above is so clearly valid and fruitful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that my DB permissions prevented my DB user from reading that particular table.  using `GRANT SELECT ...` fixed the issue.  Also, [DBAL team traced it to a DB Permissions peculiarity returning NULL in MySQL and SQL Server](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/1990).

Comment: I also had this issue. I recreated the database and it worked `console doctrine:database:drop --force;console doctrine:database:create`

Answer (score 28):

Check that the column names used in 'index' and 'uniqueContraints' schema definitions actually exist:

For example using Annotations:

`@ORM\Table(name="user_password_reset_keys", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="key_idx", columns={"key"})} )`

I had renamed my column from 'key' to 'reset_key' and this column name mismatch caused the error

```
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reset_key", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $resetKey;
```

Comment: That saved me some banging my head against the wall. After doing a full code search and addressing every possible instance of this column, it turned out to be an index that used underscores, so my code searches weren't finding it.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but may be helps some one
I had the same problem. It was because I used Symphony's command line to create my entity and camel case calling some of its properties. Then, when Doctrine create the table, also via command line, it change camel case for "_ "convention.

Answer (score -1):

I was using a ORM Designer software called Skipper that exports my Entities for me. My problem for just one table only out of 30. Was that I was missing the name attribute on my annotations. Example.

```
@ORM\Column(name="isActive", ....
```

I added that attribute "name=" and it worked again!

Comment: I disagree, it does pertain to the topic. I had the same problem but it was caused by software. Naming the software will help others find this solution that have the same problem in the software. I am not advertising nor endorsing this software, just contributing to the community to help others with the same problem I have. So please abstain from these kind of posts as it just justifies trolling.